# ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() creates additional tables that are not in the .edmx model

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, objectcontext

I have the following code:

```
HorekoEntities db = new HorekoEntities(Utils.GetDbConnStrByName(db_name));
if (!db.DatabaseExists())
{
    db.CreateDatabase();
}
```

which creates a database with tables from the HorekoEntities model.
The problem is that it adds 3 additional tables that are not in that model. I had those tables in the model but i deleted them from model and from the database as well.

On debagging I can not see those tables in `db` and they are not in the `db.CreateDatabaseScript()`. (I read somewhere that `CreateDatabase()` first calls `CreateDatabaseScript()` and then creates the database with that script)

The MSDN documentation describes the method as :

"Creates the database by using the current data source connection and the metadata in the StoreItemCollection."

I am trying to find out whats in `StoreItemCollection` but I can't figure out how to get to it.
Maybe `StoreItemCollection` is somehow caching those 3 tables?

The other thing that is maybe important is that this problem only happens with the connection string from our live server. Locally on my machine it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You deleted the tables from the context using the designer, right? They're still in your SSDL. Open your EDMX as text (XML editor), search for the table name, and remove any reference to that table.

Comment: I checked and those tables are not in the designer. They are not anywhere in the project.

Comment: Don't look in the designer. Look in the EDMX.

Comment: The extra tables are not anywhere in the project. I searched in Object Browser for them, in HorekoEntities.Designer.cs, in the xml that is behind the .edmx. For the time being I will leave them there, and return to them when I have more time.(hopefully sooner than later)

Comment: I would only expect to see them in the XML. I would not expect to see them in Designer.cs or the Object Browser. The XML is the source of the store items.